# Usage question: "to come at someone" vs "to approach someone"

Tags: word-usage

Can I paraphase:

> Jeep was approaching me at high speed.

With:

> Jeep was coming at me at high speed.

Saw usage: *to come to somebody*, but never *to come at somebody* (in the meaning *to approach somebody*).

Comment: If the jeep is _coming at you_, it implies that it is going to hit you. If it is merely approaching, that may be coincidental, or you may expect it to stop for you.

Comment: wonderful point. @oerkelens this makes it a good answer.

Comment: I'd not prefer using *approaching* with a vehicle.

Comment: @MaulikV I agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something (in this case a jeep) is *coming at you*, it implies that it is going to hit you.

If it is merely approaching you, it is coming closer, but it doesn't imply anything else. You may be expecting it to stop for you, for instance.

Coming *at* someone means approaching to hit, to attack:

> The car came at him at a ridiculous speed. *he'd better run away!*
>   She came at me with a knife. *she is attacking me!*

Coming *to* someone is a lot more peaceful:

> The car came to him at a ridiculous speed. *but then it stopped and he got it*
>   She came to me with a knife. *which I asked her to bring me*

Answer (score 1):

The statement "Jeep was approaching me at high speed." 
cannot be rephrased as "Jeep was coming at me at high speed."
because
the second statement has the latent meaning to either kill you or hurt you.

The phrase "coming at someone/something" shows the intent to hurt someone/something as if that person/thing has made you angry and now you want to take revenge.